# Make Flow require a Type when a generic function is called

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How can I make Flow require a generic Type be specified when the function is called?

```js
// @flow strict

type Person = {
  _id: string,
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

type WrapperObj = {
  genericFn<T>(string): T | null,
}

function testFunc (obj: WrapperObj, name: string) {
  // Goal: have flow produce error on the following line because generic is missing...
  const jack = obj.genericFn(name)
  if (jack) {
    // ...so that this line produces an error
    jack.height
  }
}
```

[Try Flow link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHdQGcAuAnAlgYxQKFygJ4AOApqAAqlpKwB2oAvKAN66igD6GAJgFzJ0GOgHMANO1B0AhgFtSA1JlESO0kQqkBXWQCNqEgL74iZUAHU004mTQB5XQCsmrSRrrVsAMToAeACoAfAAUSsIiAJQC-qAAPtrQ0Eb4kFp0OBj0oCikqF5pWKDBsE4Clta2Do5iUnKaYaIRrhwgoADisNLQAgAW0gBu5DAIoMRosDxaWOTU42igWSg9Q7CJCOGg0MLk+ljSWkjk7p6FGEigsmdI4QB0d5JY9KigjtJYANYuJY43x5hYPmCMnkEUkGEgRVeHyabA4LTAdxutGyfRQKLOm22o3Gk2m52kDFmsDQkg4UPeN2WGBEPTwHGMxiAA)

If I supply types on line 15 in either of these ways:

`const jack = obj.genericFn<Person>(name)`

`const jack: Person | null = obj.genericFn(name)`

...then Flow properly gives the error on line 18 as I would expect.

It seems Flow is inferring type `T` as `any` when actually we want it to complain about a missing type.

Comment: It seems to you just need to specify the type for returned value. If you don't - then flow simply doesn't know what should be checked.

Comment: Such patterns are highly suspicious. You can't do anything based on the type because it's not correlated with an argument.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes, I agree.  Unfortunately we don't control the "genericFn", its provided by the nodejs MongoDB driver.  It's the `db.collection(myCollectionName)` function.  Our hope is to get Flow's help correlating the type of the return with the parameter, or at least complaining when devs don't include the type when `db.collection()` is called.

Comment: I think what you want here is a way to associate a specific collection name string with a specific result type. In that way you wouldn't need or want to require passing the type argument explicitly.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal.  Do you happen to have an example of a flow type definition that does that?